# Bot Framework Composer Stuck on Starting Server

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I've just install Bot Framework Composer and when I try to start it up it just gets stuck on starting server and it never continues or start up successfully. Please assist, I don't know what's causing this.

[image]

Comment: Have you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, could you please check whether the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable files are installed.

In some environments, Microsoft Bot Composer may not work correctly if these files aren't installed.

For instructions on how to install `vc_redist.arm64.exe`, see [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170).